# Salvar dados do formulário sem obrigação de atualizar a imagem

Tags: php, mysql, html5, codeigniter

Tenho um formulário de cadastro e este formulário tem uma imagem de perfil do usuário cadastrado.

O `insert` e `update` da imagem estão funcionando perfeitamente.

O problema está em quando atualizo qualquer dado que não seja a imagem, o sistema não salva, retornando erro de upload de imagem.

O formulário não está aceitando o input file vazio e quer atualizar a imagem de qualquer forma.

O que eu quero:
Editar e Salvar CPF ou NOME.
Manter IMAGEM que já está cadastrado sem obrigação de altera-la

**Parte do código  HTML - PHP - CSS - JAVASCRIPT**

```js
function preview(fileInput) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {           
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;     
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }           
        var img=document.getElementById("avatar");            
        img.file = file;    
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) { 
            return function(e) { 
                aImg.src = e.target.result; 
            }; 
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }    
}
```

```css
#avatar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover; 
 border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse in accordion-body" id="collapseGOne"><!--Dados Pessoais-->
<div class="widget-content ">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 14%">
            <?php if (!empty($result->url_foto)) { ?>
                <img id="avatar" src="<?php echo $result->url_foto; ?>" >
            <?php }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </td>
<td>
    <div class="span12" style="padding: 1%">
        <div class="span4">
        <?php echo form_hidden('idColaboradores',$result->idColaboradores) ?>
            <label for="nome">Nome<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="nome" class="span12" type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $result->nome; ?>"  />
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <label for="sexo">Sexo<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="span12" value="">
                <option <?php if($result->sexo == 'Masculino'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                 <option <?php if($result->sexo == 'Feminino'){echo 'selected';} ?> value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span12" style="padding: 1%; margin-left: 0">
        <div class="span2">
            <label for="cpf">CPF<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="cpf" class="span12 cpf" type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="000.000.000-00" value="<?php echo $result->cpf; ?>"  />
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <label for="rg">RG<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="rg" class="span12" type="text" name="rg" value="<?php echo $result->rg; ?>"  />
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <label for="data_nascimento">Data Nascimento<span class="required">*</span></label>
             <input id="data_nascimento" class="span12" type="date" name="data_nascimento" value="<?php echo $result->data_nascimento; ?>"  />
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class=""><!--input Foto-->
    <label for="" class="control-label"><span class="required">Foto*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" onchange="preview(this)" name="userfile" /> (.png, .jpg, .jpeg)
    </div>
</div><!--input Foto-->
    
</div><!--Dados Pessoais-->
```

**Parte do código Controller - PHP**

```html
function editar() {

        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eColaborador')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para editar colaboradores.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

        if ($this->form_validation->run('colaboradores') == false) {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
        } else {
            $data_admissao = $this->input->post('data_admissao');
   $data_demissao = $this->input->post('data_demissao');
   
   $foto = $this->do_upload();

         $file = $foto['file_name'];
         $url_foto = base_url().'assets/fotos/'.date('d-m-Y').'/'.$file;

            try {

            }catch (Exception $e) {
               $data_admissao = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_demissao = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_aviso = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_aviso = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_ferias = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_ferias = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_abandono1 = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_abandono15 = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_abandono28 = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_previdencia = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_previdencia = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_justica_a = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_justica_a = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_justica_i = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_justica_i = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_licasamento = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_licasamento = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_inicio_suspensao = date('Y/m/d');
      $data_fim_suspensao = date('Y/m/d');
            }
  
            $data = array(
                'nome' => $this->input->post('nome'),
                'sexo' => $this->input->post('sexo'),
    'cpf' => $this->input->post('cpf'),
    'rg' => $this->input->post('rg'),
    'url_foto' => $url_foto,
    'data_nascimento' => $this->input->post('data_nascimento'),
                'rua' => $this->input->post('rua'),
                'numero' => $this->input->post('numero'),
    'complemento' => $this->input->post('complemento'),
                'bairro' => $this->input->post('bairro'),
                'cep' => $this->input->post('cep'),
                'estado' => $this->input->post('estado'),
                'cidade' => $this->input->post('cidade'),
    'telefone' => $this->input->post('telefone'),
                'celular' => $this->input->post('celular'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'ctps'=> $this->input->post('ctps'),
    'serie' => $this->input->post('serie'),
    'uf' => $this->input->post('uf'),
    'pis' => $this->input->post('pis'), 
    'salario' => $this->input->post('salario'),
    'banco' => $this->input->post('banco'),
    'agencia' => $this->input->post('agencia'),
    'conta' => $this->input->post('conta'),
    'jornada_trabalho'=> $this->input->post('jornada_trabalho'),
    'horario_trabalho' => $this->input->post('horario_trabalho'),
    'data_admissao' => $this->input->post('data_admissao'),
    'departamento' => $this->input->post('departamento'),
    'cargo' => $this->input->post('cargo'),
    'situacao' => $this->input->post('situacao'),
    'data_demissao' => $this->input->post('data_demissao'),
    'tipo_demissao' => $this->input->post('tipo_demissao'),
    'motivo_demissao' => $this->input->post('motivo_demissao'),
    'data_inicio_aviso' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_aviso'),
    'data_fim_aviso' => $this->input->post('data_fim_aviso'),
    'data_inicio_ferias' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_ferias'),
    'data_fim_ferias' => $this->input->post('data_fim_ferias'),
    'data_abandono1' => $this->input->post('data_abandono1'),
    'data_abandono15' => $this->input->post('data_abandono15'),
    'data_abandono28' => $this->input->post('data_abandono28'),
    'data_inicio_previdencia' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_previdencia'),
    'data_fim_previdencia' => $this->input->post('data_fim_previdencia'),
    'data_inicio_justica_a' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_justica_a'),
    'data_fim_justica_a' => $this->input->post('data_fim_justica_a'),
    'data_inicio_justica_i' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_justica_i'),
    'data_inicio_licasamento' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_licasamento'),
    'data_fim_licasamento' => $this->input->post('data_fim_licasamento'),
    'data_inicio_limaternidade' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_limaternidade'),
    'data_fim_limaternidade' => $this->input->post('data_fim_limaternidade'),
    'data_inicio_suspensao' => $this->input->post('data_inicio_suspensao'),
    'data_fim_suspensao' => $this->input->post('data_fim_suspensao'),
    'observacao' => $this->input->post('observacao'),
    'usuario_alteracao' => $this->input->post('usuario_alteracao'),
    'data_alteracao' => date('Y-m-d')
            );

            if ($this->colaboradores_model->edit('colaboradores', $data, 'idColaboradores', $this->input->post('idColaboradores')) == TRUE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Colaborador editado com sucesso!');
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/colaboradores/editar/'.$this->input->post('idColaboradores'));
            } else {
                $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>An Error Occured</p></div>';
            }
        }
  
  $this->load->model('departamentos_model');
        $this->data['departamentos'] = $this->departamentos_model->getActive('departamentos','departamentos.idDepartamentos,departamentos.departamento');
  $this->load->model('cargos_model');
        $this->data['cargos'] = $this->departamentos_model->getActive('cargos','cargos.idCargos,cargos.cargo');
  
  $this->data['result'] = $this->colaboradores_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->data['view'] = 'colaboradores/editarColaborador';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);
     
    }
```

**Função Upload**

```html
      public function do_upload(){

        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vColaborador')){
          $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar colaboradores.');
          redirect(base_url());
        }
 
     $date = date('d-m-Y');

  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/fotos/'.$date;
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf|PDF|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG';
     $config['max_size']     = 0;
     $config['max_width']  = '3000';
     $config['max_height']  = '2000';
     $config['encrypt_name'] = true;


  if (!is_dir('./assets/fotos/'.$date)) {

   mkdir('./assets/fotos/' . $date, 0777, TRUE);

  }

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
  {
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

   $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Erro ao fazer upload do arquivo, verifique se a extensão do arquivo é permitida.');
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/colaboradores/adicionar/');
  }
  else
  {
   //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
   return $this->upload->data();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Incluí a função upload no exemplo acima, para melhor entendimento...

Alguém mais pode ajudar, tentei fazer como Daniel disse e não consegui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu coloco sempre assim:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
     //definicoes do UPLOAD aqui
}
```

Dessa forma, ele só faz o upload se eu carregar um arquivo

Comment: eu Consegui.

Agradeço demais a ajuda!

Comment: finaliza a questão e marca a reposta para que a solução possa ser usada por outras pessoas

Answer (score 0):

Separa a inserção da imagem no banco e apenas executa o update caso o usuário tenha feito o upload de algo.

Comment: No controller, tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

**if($url_foto != null){

$data = array(
...
...**

Sendo que, se o input file for diferente de nulo, faz o update e se for igual a nulo, não faz o update.

Mas não funcionou

@Daniel

Comment: Porque ele ta inserindo o null no banco, cria uma função separada pro upload e gravação da imagem, assim só execute essa função se o input da imagem estiver "preenchido"

Comment: Baseado no código acima,
Tem alguma sugestão?

Já tentei utilizando a mesma função do upload e não deu.

Incluí no post a função de upload que estou usando